# Looking for windows equivalent of the unix script command

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

The unix command "script" allows a user to run programs/commands, and when ctrl-d is pressed, the output is written to a file. A timestamp of the session is also written in this file. Is there is a equivalent command in Windows/Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is Cygwin an option?  The script command can be found in the `util-linux` package.